# Set frame position of decorated GtkWindow on screen

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I have a task to restore window **frame** position on screen on program startup - so to define initial window position.

Consider the following decorated GtkWindow instance on Linux:

[image]

The window has two principal boxes: frame box and client box.

And there are two GTK functions that allow to set size and position of the window on screen:

[gtk_window_move()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move) - sets window's **frame** box position on screen and

[gtk_window_resize](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-resize) - sets window's **client** box size.

Question:

Is there any way in GTK to define initial **frame** placement of the window?

On Windows I can do that by calling `MoveWindow()` and on MacOS `NSWindow setFrame` method. But on GTK... Am I asking too much?

Comment: What do you expect to use? A x,y coordinate? Center of the screen? Other?

Comment: I need exactly what MoveWindow does on Windows : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow 

It uses desktop pixel coordinates. Multiple monitors are combined to single desktop space so they contained in single outline rectangle. MoveWindow uses coordinates in that box.

Comment: I would like to know if I am understanding right this. **1)** You have a screen where it’s Resolution could be eg 1440/900. **2)** You need to know programmatically which screen size uses the monitor. **3)** Once that you know it programmatically, then you need to set your window based on its screen size to a fixed position. Do I understand it Right? If not, could you please provide more information about this?

Comment: @Michi. First case: to be able to restore the window to the position user left it in previous session. Second case: I want dialog window to be aligned with its parent window. Both windows use decorations.

Comment: @c-smile Probably GSettings is what you need =>> https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html#GSettings.description.  Read also about [First Steps With GSettings](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/05/01/first-steps-with-gsettings/)

Comment: @Michi How GSettings will help me to implement `MoveWindow(wnd, frameBox)` ?

Comment: @c-smile you do not implement it with GSetting. You need that after the user uses your application and makes some changes to it, like in your case he move the window to a new position, after the user close the application and run it again, the position of the window should be there where the user left it before he Closed it.  If I am right (because this is what I understand what you ask) then GSetting should do the job.

Comment: [Please Read This](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/SaveWindowState).

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the "realize" signal for the window (*important*: before calling gtk_widget_show). Then call gtk_window_move from the handler:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_window_realize(GtkWidget *widget,
                       gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW(user_data);
  gtk_window_move(window, 100, 40);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkWidget *window = NULL;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect(window,
                   "realize",
                   G_CALLBACK(on_window_realize),
                   (gpointer)window);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not so sure I understand how this is related to my question. How your code will help to define dimensions of window **frame** at startup? 

Your code just moves frame to point 100, 40. But you can do that already and without need of handling realize event.

Comment: Hi, I thought your question was about placing the window frame at a specific position (i.e. the X and Y arguments of MoveWindow) at startup. And yes, you can do that without connecting to the "realize" signal. You can just call gtk_window_move and then show the window. So you want to set a value for the whole window frame dimension (taking in account the window decorations)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to set the whole frame dimension, only the client area dimension. As a workaround you can use CSD (Client Side Decoration) with a GtkHeaderBar. Then you can get the GtkHeaderBar allocated size and account for that when calling gtk_window_resize

Comment: "I don't think there is a way to set the whole frame dimension..."  that is what I discovered too before asking.

For me lack of such basic UI function in GTK appeared so strange that I decided to ask to verify that I haven't missed anything...  set-window-frame-box-on-screen functionality is in any decent GUI OS environment but not GTK for some reasons. Strange.